# Make simple [C#]

Tags: c#

is possible this wrote simple, code is here:

```
foreach (var friend in friends)
{
    friend.Value.blockQuote = GetBlockQuote(friend.Value.nick);

    if (friend.Value.photo == "0")
    {
        if (friend.Value.sex == 1)
        {
            var img = new BitmapImage();
            img.BeginInit();
            img.UriSource = new Uri(@"avatars\man.jpg",
                                    UriKind.Relative);
            img.EndInit();
            friend.Value.profilePhoto = img;
        }
        if (friend.Value.sex == 2)
        {
            //da default
            var img = new BitmapImage();
            img.BeginInit();
            img.UriSource = new Uri(@"avatars\woman.jpg",
                                    UriKind.Relative);
            img.EndInit();
            friend.Value.profilePhoto = img;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var img = new BitmapImage();
        img.BeginInit();
        img.UriSource = new Uri(friend.Value.photo.Replace(@"\", "").Replace(@"s_", ""), UriKind.Absolute);
        img.EndInit();
        friend.Value.profilePhoto = img;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break out the uri-setting part

```
foreach (var friend in friends)
{
    friend.Value.blockQuote = GetBlockQuote(friend.Value.nick);

    Uri uri;
    if (friend.Value.photo == "0")
    {
        if (friend.Value.sex == 1)
        {
            uri = new Uri(@"avatars\man.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
        }
        else if (friend.Value.sex == 2)
        {
            //da default
            uri = new Uri(@"avatars\woman.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
        }
        else
        {
            uri = null; // insert error handling here
        }
    }
    else
    {
        uri = new Uri(friend.Value.photo.Replace(@"\", "").Replace(@"s_", ""), UriKind.Absolute);
    }
    var img = new BitmapImage();
    img.BeginInit();
    img.UriSource = uri;
    img.EndInit();
    friend.Value.profilePhoto = img;
}
```

**Edit**
Note that the if-else-part is now a good candidate for Refactor->Extract method

Comment: Good answer, but a minor nit:  That's probably going to give you an uninitialized variable error because `uri` isn't definitely assigned.  What happens if `friend.Value.sex` isn't 1 or 2?

Comment: @Jim Mischel, already discovered that and updated the example.

Comment: @Jim Mischel, that was actually why I don't initialized the `uri` variable when declaring it, to catch those errors, but my head did not work that well as a compiler...

Comment: to Jim Mischel, friend.Value.sex can be 1 or 2. No other values.

Comment: @Markus: Assumption is the path that leads to bug-ridden code. If it can be only one of two values, use an `enum` type instead of an integer.

Answer (score 2):

You could factor out the lines

```
var img = new BitmapImage();
img.BeginInit();
```

and

```
img.EndInit();
friend.Value.profilePhoto = img;
```

by putting them before (for the former) and after (for the latter) the `if`/`else` block.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var friend in friends)
{
    friend.Value.blockQuote = GetBlockQuote(friend.Value.nick);
    var img = new BitmapImage();
    img.BeginInit();

    if (friend.Value.photo == "0")
    {
        if (friend.Value.sex == 1)
        {
             img.UriSource = new Uri(@"avatars\man.jpg",
        }
        if (friend.Value.sex == 2)
        {
             img.UriSource = new Uri(@"avatars\woman.jpg",
                                                UriKind.Relative);
        }
     }
     else
     {
          img.UriSource = new Uri(friend.Value.photo.Replace(@"\", "").Replace(@"s_", ""), UriKind.Absolute);

     }

     img.EndInit();
     friend.Value.profilePhoto = img;
}
```